# ObservableCollection not update my UI

Tags: wpf, listview

This is my Model:

```
public class WiresharkFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    virtual public void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

   private string _file; // file path
   private string _packets; // how many packet in file
   private string _sentPackets; // how many packet sent
   private string _progress; // percentage (_sentPackets/_packets) * 100

   public int Progress
   {
       get { return _progress; }
       set
       {
           _progress = value;
           NotifyPropertyChange("Progress");
       }
   }

   public void Transmit(WireshrkFile)
   {
         // here i am send the packets
   }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    virtual public void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My model collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<WireshrkFile> files{ get; set; }
```

My `ListView`:

```
    <ListView Name="lvFiles" Margin="16,455,0,65" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding pcapFiles}" MouseDoubleClick="lvPcapFiles_MouseDoubleClick" 
              MouseDown="lvPcapFiles_MouseDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="lvPcapFiles_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD8D5D5"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF15669E"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF15669E"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                <Grid Margin="-6">
                    <ProgressBar Name="progressBarColumn" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}" 
                                 Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
                                 Height="20" Margin="0" Background="Gray" Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn, StringFormat={}{0}%}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" Foreground="White" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarTemplate">
                <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
                <!-- file name column -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="420" Header="File name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" />

                <!-- duration column -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Duration" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}" />

                <!-- packets column -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Packets" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Packets}" />

                <!-- packet sent -->
                <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Packet sent" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PacketsSent}" />

                <!-- progress column -->
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ProgressCell"  Width="50" Header="Progress" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Open Capture" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif"
                              Click="MenuItem_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Height="18" Width="18" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Source="C:\Users\rsteinbe\Dropbox\PacketPlayer\PacketPlayer\resources\wireshark.ico" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
    </ListView>
```

I can see that my  collection properties changing but mu `UI` not.

Comment: Haven't you implemented NotifyPropertyChange for all WiresharkFile properties? By the way, transform them from normal fields to public properties.

Comment: Yes i did it, see my update

Comment: So you are talking only about the Progress property which feeds the ProgressBar when you say that your UI is not updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Pay attention here: `ItemsSource="{Binding WiresharkFile}"`

Change this to `ItemsSource="{Binding files}"`

I've prepared a small sample:

```
Window x:Class="ProgressBarChangedStack.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding files}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Progress: "/>
                        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Margin="5" MinWidth="100"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Click to complete progress" Width="150" Margin="10" Click="btnProgressComplete_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Simple View, you have a `ProgressBar` there with its `Value` bound to a property from the Model.

This is the Model:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Progress;

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _Progress; }
        set
        {
            _Progress = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Progress"));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

I think there is nothing to explain here, you have the same approach.

And here is my testing code:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> files { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        files = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        files.Add(new Model() { Progress = 20 });
        files.Add(new Model() { Progress = 30 });
        files.Add(new Model() { Progress = 40 });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnProgressComplete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            file.Progress = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

So, when i click the Button, all the ProgressBars will be complete.

I see you don't have INPC implemented for these properties:

```
  private string _file; // file path
  private string _packets; // how many packet in file
  private string _sentPackets; // how many packet sent
  private string _progress; // percentage (_sentPackets/_packets) * 100
```

With their actual form, the View will not be inform when changes occur.

Comment: What's this INPC implemented ? i have the NotifyPropertyChange on each set, do i need something elae ? i also add ListView.Resources with my progress bar

Comment: @VerintVerint for _file, _packets and _sentPackets do the same thing you did for Progress. Implement them as a public property and on the set add NotifyPropertyChange.

Comment: I did it all and still i cannot see my collection updated my UI, i opened the work with another thread so my Ui not freezing but this still not working, what could be the problem ?

Comment: I just saw your btnProgressComplete_Click, why you doing this ? ObservableCollection cannot update my UI automatically ?

Comment: @VerintVerint ItemsSource="{Binding WiresharkFile}", i think there is a mistake here. You might have wanted to set ItemsSource to files collection.

Comment: @VerintVerint yes it can, because here is a collection of Model, and that collection is set as ItemsSource for my ListView. Check the ItemTemplate for the ListView and how am I getting the Progress value.

Comment: I added all my ListView definition, please see my update, i also have another property that remained the same - duration, this is also need to add to NotifyPropertyChange ? BTW my collection called pcapFiles so this name is OK

Comment: Yes, if you want your View to get updated when you change properties values, you need to implement that INPC interface, and to add the PropertyChanged for all of the properties, just as you did in the first place with the Progress property.

Comment: OK i did it and again this is not update my UI, i think this may be my ListView definition, can you please take a look ?

Comment: @VerintVerint Can you please implement my sample and see how the things work and relate with each other?

Comment: But i don't need this button click, what i need to change in your code in order to my UI will updated automatically in case my collection changing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80524/discussion-between-olaru-mircea-and-verint-verint).